# how do I write pytest result to a csv?

Tags: pytest

I am collecting the results from each test in pytest in a csv file so that I can push the result to Jama.
How do i collect the results from each pytest.
I see the last line of the function, for example, "assert x == y" is the last step usually, and the function returns at that point. I am looking to capture that result into csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the simplest way this could be done:

```
try:
    assert a == 4    
    print "True"
except AssertionError as e:
    print "False"
```

Hope this helps!